# changing text for a selected option only when its in selected mode

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure if I confused everyone with the above title. My problem is as follows.

I am using standard javascript (no jQuery) and HTML for my code. The requirement is that for the `<select>...</select>` menu, I have a dynamic list of varying length.

Now if the length of the `option[selectedIndex].text > 43` characters, I want to change the       `option[selectecIndex]` to a new text.

I am able to do this by calling

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].text = "changed text";
```

in the onChange event which works fine. The issue here is once the user decides to change the selection, the dropdownlist is showing the pervious-selected-text with changed text. This needs to show the original list.

I am stumped! is there a simpler way to do this?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3):

You can store previous text value in some data attribute and use it to reset text back when necessary:

```
document.getElementById('test').onchange = function() {

    var option = this.options[this.selectedIndex];

    option.setAttribute('data-text', option.text);
    option.text = "changed text";

    // Reset texts for all other options but current
    for (var i = this.options.length; i--; ) {
        if (i == this.selectedIndex) continue;
        var text = this.options[i].getAttribute('data-text');
        if (text) this.options[i].text = text;
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kb7CW/

Comment: this works like what I already have. As in when I select lets say 'option 1', as soon as I select it, it changes to "changed text" and is shown as selected. Now when I click the drop down again, 'option 1' is now coming in as 'changed text'. I want to always show the drop down options as the original list!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it pretty simply with jquery. Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kb7CW/1/

Here is the script for it also:

```
      //check if the changed text option exists, if so, hide it
$("select").on('click', function(){
   if($('option#changed').length > 0)
   {
        $("#changed").hide()
   }
});
//bind on change
$("select").on('change', function(){
    var val = $(":selected").val(); //get the value of the selected item
    var text = $(':selected').html(); //get the text inside the option tag
    $(":selected").removeAttr('selected'); //remove the selected item from the selectedIndex
    if($("#changed").length <1) //if the changed option doesn't exist, create a new option with the text you want it to have (perhaps substring 43 would be right
          $(this).append('<option id="changed" value =' + val + ' selected="selected">Changed Text</option>');
    else
        $('#changed').val(val) //if it already exists, change its value

   $(this).prop('selectedIndex', $("#changed").prop('index')); //set the changed text option to selected;

});
```

Comment: the issue is that I am and cannot use jQuery. Was looking for a standard JavaScript way of handling the issue.

Comment: You can conver that to standard javascript pretty easily. It is just a pain to insert the DOM elements without jquery.

Comment: i'll try. I don't come from a jQuery background so will take me a while to understand and change. Anyways thanks! :)

Comment: I added comments to make it a little easier to follow.